# Java Print out all numbers in a math-sequence

Tags: java

I want the program to print out every number that each digit to the power to 3 added together will equal that number. For instance, the number 153: `1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153.`

This is the code, but I do not know why it does not work.

Edit: The reason I have `siffra++;` is because I want it to test all numbers to `500`. This is what I got now, but it does still now work (not showing anything in `JOptionPane`):

```
int siffra = 153;

String allaSiffror = "";
int count = 0;

if (siffra < 500) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String siffran = Integer.toString(siffra);
        String selekt = siffran.substring(i,i+1);
        int selekta = Integer.parseInt(selekt);
        count += Math.pow(selekta,3);
            if (count == siffra) {
                System.out.println(count);
                allaSiffror += count + " ";
                count = 0;
            } 
            siffra++;
    }
}


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, allaSiffror);
```

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work', what isn't it doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such numbers are called **Armstrong numbers**
**Firstly your mistakes** 
 1) Your are making **count(sum I assumed) 0** only **if you find number matching** your condition like 153...what **if number is not matching then shouldn't the count/sum be zero** for new number.
 2) **Secondly you are saying that, you want to test numbers till 500 but you are using if condition which would be exectued only once**...so use loop over there

**Few suggestions** I would make 
1)Instead of using String use StringBuilder.
2)Also instead of converting integer to string and then using substring directly work with integer only

So modify code as follows

```
 int siffra = 153;

 StringBuilder allaSiffror = new StringBuilder();
 int count;

 while(siffra<500){
     count = 0;
     int temp = siffra;

     int num;
     while(temp>0){
       num=temp%10;  
       temp=temp/10;
       count += Math.pow(num,3);  
     }

     if (count == siffra){
       System.out.println(count);
       allaSiffror.append(count + " ");
     } 
     siffra++;
 }
System.out.println(allaSiffror.toString());


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, allaSiffror.toString());
```

> Update o/p is as follows :
>
> ```
> 153
> 370
> 371
> 407
> 153 370 371 407
> ```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that this part is outside of the loop:

```
String siffran = Integer.toString(siffra);
int count = 0;
```

so your count adds up every number to the previous, and since you increase siffra but work on siffran- you're checking 100 all the time

aside from that, I'd also take @Sluth's advice - no need to convert back and forth to string and int - use mathematical mod and % to get the digits

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand some mistakes I've done. Please check the edit in my question and tell me where I've gone wrong now.